# DC 3-12V Water pump connected to power source doesn't work

Tags: dc, 5v

I'm trying to make a simple connection of 3-12V Water Pump to a power supply(https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07D3XS91J?ref_=pe_1365641_54848841).

I'm using power supply which is 5V (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01ELGR26I?ref_=pe_1365641_54848841).

I have made simple connection, whith positive on power supply to positive on pump, and same with negative.

When I turn on the power supply, it's LED turns green for fraction on second and water pump starts, but then it goes off and repeats.

As Im absolute beginner, please point me in any direction. Thank You.

Comment: you have already got an answer which suggests you have far too weak power supply. You have not shown a slightest numerical data of your power supply, so the answer is plausible. If you have the data, show it. Do not offer links which tell that some power supply maybe will be included.

Comment: the top link says that the pump uses this motor .... http://www.robotstorehk.com/motors/doc/rs_360sh.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon link for the pump recommends a power supply of 5 volts that can supply 2 amperes.  The Amazon link for the power supply says that the maximum output of the supply is only 700 ma. So that's your problem: the power supply cannot supply the current required by the pump. Solution: get a more powerful power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Your power supply does not provide enough current for the motor, it's as simple as that.

EDIT: Links to a vendor like amazon (or ebay or aliexpress) are often of little value. You should try to provide links to an actual manufacturer's data sheet. If you can't find the manufacturer's data sheet then don't buy the product. It's buried toward the bottom, but the listing for your motor does tell you how much current it needs...and not to bother trying to use a supply that provides less current.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any junk wall warts, just about any would work for you. Cut the plug off and connect the motor. Just don't go over 12v and if you get the + - wrong it will just run backwards.

correct your motor needs 2 amp or better, many ww will meet this.

Comment: No, a wall wart that provides 300mA or 500mA or 800mA will not work.